# Why has git deprecated git update to git update-git-for-windows?

Tags: git

Well, the question is in the title, but still:

Why has `git` deprecated `git update` to `git update-git-for-windows`?

`git update` seems more logical to me...

Comment: detailed explanations of this can be found here https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/pull/167 and https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/master/ReleaseNotes.md#bug-fixes-9

Comment: are you sure that you meant to use "npm update ..." ?